# Difference between datatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow> and datatable.AsEnumerable() in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on same datatable related operation on data, what would be the most efficient way to use linq on datatable-

```
var list = dataSet.Tables[0]
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Where(p => p.Field<String>("EmployeeName") == "Jams");
```

OR

```
var listobj =  (EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>) dataSet.Tables[0].Rows
  .Cast<DataRow>()
  .Where(dr => dr["EmployeeName"].ToString() == "Jams");
```

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, `AsEnumerable()` returns `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>`
which if you look into the code for this, you will see the following:

`this._enumerableRows = Enumerable.Cast<TRow>((IEnumerable) table.Rows);`

So I would say that they are basically equivalent!

Answer (score 1):

`.AsEnumerable()` internally uses `.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()`, at least in the [reference implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/EnumerableRowCollection.cs,068ee8343125ebde,references). It does a few other bits as well but nothing that would appreciably affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

[`.AsEnumerable()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/EnumerableRowCollection.cs,068ee8343125ebde) and [`.Field`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataRowExtensions.cs,983e71f849a1f6c2) do a lot of extra work that is not needed in most cases.

Also, field lookup by index is faster than lookup by name:

```
int columnIndex = dataTable.Columns["EmployeeName"].Ordinal;

var list = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(dr => "Jams".Equals(dr[columnIndex]));
```

---

For multiple names, the lookup is faster if the results are cached in a `Dictionary` or `Lookup`:

```
int colIndex = dataTable.Columns["EmployeeName"].Ordinal;

var lookup = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToLookup(dr => dr[colIndex]?.ToString());

// .. and later when the result is needed:
var list = lookup["Jams"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Define "efficient".

From performance standpoint, I doubt that there are any significant differences between these two options: the overall run-time will be dominated by the time required to do network I/O, not the time required to do casting.

From pure code style point of view, second one looks too unelegant to me. If you can get away with all-LINQ solution, go with it as it's generally (IMO, at least) more readable by virtue of being declarative.